# Processing Toxiclibs: hide axes/normals when drawing trianglemesh

Tags: java, opengl, javafx, processing

I am using **toxiclibs** to draw an imported binary .stl file as a mesh like this:

```
ToxiclibsSupport gfx;
TriangleMesh mesh;

void setup(){
    mesh = (TriangleMesh)new STLReader().loadBinary(
    sketchPath("/data/3dmodels/gun.stl"), STLReader.TRIANGLEMESH);
    gfx = new ToxiclibsSupport(this);
}

void draw(){
    translate(width/2, height/2, 300);
    gfx.origin(new Vec3D(), 100);
    noStroke();
    fill(fxColor.getRed(), fxColor.getGreen(), fxColor.getBlue());
    gfx.mesh(model, false, 0);
    translate(-width/2, -height/2, -300);
}
```

Toxiclibs shows the xyz-axes by default as shown here:

[image: xyz-axes image]

I want to disable the draw of those axes, but can't seem to find anything related.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just get rid of the call to `gfx.origin()`? According to [the Toxiclibs API](http://toxiclibs.org/docs/p5/), that's what's drawing the axis lines.